# Dynamic select not working with Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, materialize

materialize css not working with dynamic select. Its working fine with countries but not showing states.

I think there is some problem with the jquery.

Please check my code snippet.

I have checked everything on the internet. But nothing works for me.

```js
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia" );

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2]="Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3]="Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4]="Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5]="Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6]="Anguilla";
s_a[7]="Antartica";
s_a[8]="Barbuda|Redonda|Saint George|Saint John|Saint Mary|Saint Paul|Saint Peter|Saint Philip";
s_a[9]="Antartica e Islas del Atlantico Sur|Buenos Aires|Buenos Aires Capital Federal|Catamarca|Chaco|Chubut|Cordoba|Corrientes|Entre Rios|Formosa|Jujuy|La Pampa|La Rioja|Mendoza|Misiones|Neuquen|Rio Negro|Salta|San Juan|San Luis|Santa Cruz|Santa Fe|Santiago del Estero|Tierra del Fuego|Tucuman";
s_a[10]="Aragatsotn|Ararat|Armavir|Geghark'unik'|Kotayk'|Lorri|Shirak|Syunik'|Tavush|Vayots' Dzor|Yerevan";
// <!-- -->



function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){
 
 var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

 var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );
 
 stateElement.length=0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
 stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
 stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 
 var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");
 
 for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
  stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
 }
  $("#" + stateElementId).material_select();
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId){
 // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
 var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
 countryElement.length=0;
 countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','-1');
 countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
  countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
 }

 // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

 if( stateElementId ){
  countryElement.onchange = function(){
   populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId );
  };
 }
}

populateCountries("country", "state");

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $("#raghav"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".addmore"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('Select Country: <select id="country'+x+'" name="country" class="country"></select>  Select State: <select id="state'+x+'" name="state" class="state"></select>');
    
                populateCountries("country"+x+"", "state"+x+"");

            }
        });
});

});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group" id="raghav">  
Select Country:<select id="country" name ="country" ></select> 
Select State: <select name ="state" id ="state" class="state"></select> 
</div>  
  
<div class="button-div">
    <input type="button" name="addmore" class="addmore" value="Add More">
    </div>  
  
    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();     //select js
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`material_select().` creates a list `ul` for `select` and `li` for `options` and then `shows` this ul as `dropdown` when you call `material_select` only country dropdown is filled with data and `ul` is created for this only so its `options` are showing.

When you populate the state dropdown `ul` for this is not created so it doesn't show you need to call `material_select` when you populate the state dropdown.

```
function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );

    stateElement.length=0;  // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
    $("#" + stateElementId).material_select();
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Thanks for help. Was searching all over the internet for this finally found what i was looking for

Comment: Can you do this with adding a add more button. I added a button which clone country and state but the problem is with the help of your code i am only able to show the first instance of list. Rest clones are created but not showing the list. below is my code for add more.

Comment: $(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {  var max_fields = 10; 
var wrapper = $("#raghav"); //Fields wrapper
 var add_button = $(".addmore"); //Add button ID
var x = 1; //initial text box count
 $(add_button).click(function (e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
 if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
x++; //text box increment
$(wrapper).append('Select Country: <select id="country'+x+'" name="country" class="country"></select>  Select State: <select id="state'+x+'" name="state" class="state"></select>');
populateCountries("country"+x+"", "state"+x+"");
 }
 });  });  });

Comment: Like we did for the state dropdown when a new dropdown is created or after it is filled with data than apply material_select on that. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Please take a look i added a add more button in my code snippet.i have tried adding material_select in that dropdown but that doesn't seem to be redering

Comment: `$("#"+countryElementId).material_select()` write this line at end of populatecountries method.

Comment: I have  added  my code below and in my code snippet too . Check the last function in my js code

Comment: You have added it as answer lol add delete this as you have already added in the question.Try this `$("#"+countryElementId).material_select()` at end of populatecountries method.

Comment: i did that but thats not populating state list for the first instance. after clicking add more the states are populating. Please add a code snippet if you have achieved what i am trying to do

Comment: Ok thanks problem solved . That worked , i was missing a semicolon . Thanks again

Comment: Can you tell me how does materialize creates list of select element, i mean the process and working. Or just provide me with the link.

Comment: I have not used this before but you can check its documentation by some google search.